# How can i limit child nodes using security rules in Firebase (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-security

I am developing Turn based game using firebase. My game has game rooms and each room includes max 3 child nodes. These are Player1,Player2 and current user count. My case, Player1 created a room with 2 child nodes(Player1 ID and current user counts). Player 1 is waiting just 1 enemy. However, if 2 other players click join at the same time, the room will have 3 Players. How i can avoid this situation using security rules ?

My Related database part as text like below:

```
"QuickPlay3hanePlaying" : {
"ByVmFbUC6HS01v4SASeA2ev33zz1" : {
  "3s6TdUxImrNhMReJbS8kBh4I9im1" : {
    "IQ" : 1350,
    "date" : 1.474527951467337E9,
    "gizliSayi" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    "isReady" : 0,
    "isSiraBende" : 0,
    "isWin" : 0,
    "name" : "Emre Esen",
    "photoUrl" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/1796656_10203231676898828_1482882234_n.jpg?oh=b1600006284e4e8ca9411d804c5571a2&oe=5880E580",
    "sonTahminim" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    "uid" : "3s6TdUxImrNhMReJbS8kBh4I9im1"
  },
  "ByVmFbUC6HS01v4SASeA2ev33zz1" : {
    "IQ" : 1280,
    "date" : 1.474527943420204E9,
    "gizliSayi" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    "isReady" : 0,
    "isSiraBende" : 1,
    "isWin" : 0,
    "name" : "Emot Emot",
    "photoUrl" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14225541_330456493965915_6052582248934611374_n.jpg?oh=35c26a6ea69a3266451a33908c7a060a&oe=586E13B1",
    "sonTahminim" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    "uid" : "ByVmFbUC6HS01v4SASeA2ev33zz1"
  },
  "userSayisi" : 2
}
```

}

Create Room Code Block:

```
    func createRoom(){


    Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi = Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID

    setPlayerInfo()

    let interval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

    let info = ["photoUrl":Model.sharedInstance.userPictureUrl,
                "uid":Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID,
                "IQ":Model.sharedInstance.userIQ,
                "name":Model.sharedInstance.username,
                "isSiraBende":1,
                "gizliSayi":Model.sharedInstance.gizliSayi,
                "isReady":Model.sharedInstance.isReadyForPlaying,
                "isWin":Model.sharedInstance.isWin,
                "sonTahminim":Model.sharedInstance.rakipSonTahmini,
                "date":interval]


    Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).setValue(["userSayisi":1])

    Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).setValue(info)

    // uygulama kapatıldıgında remove olsun diye

    Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).onDisconnectRemoveValue()
    Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).child("userSayisi").onDisconnectRemoveValue()



    Model.sharedInstance.handleCreateRoom =  Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        print("SnapCount: \(snapshot.childrenCount)")

        // usersayısı ve 1 kullanıcı ile snap sayısı 2 oluyor 1 kullanıcı için

        if snapshot.childrenCount == 3 {

            print("Game Start")




            Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).removeObserverWithHandle(Model.sharedInstance.handleCreateRoom)

            Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).updateChildValues(["userSayisi":2])


            let ilkEleman = snapshot.children.allObjects[0] as! FIRDataSnapshot

            let ikinciEleman = snapshot.children.allObjects[1] as! FIRDataSnapshot

            let ucuncuEleman = snapshot.children.allObjects[2] as! FIRDataSnapshot




            print(ucuncuEleman.key)

            if ilkEleman.key != Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID && ilkEleman.key != "userSayisi" {

                 print(ilkEleman.key)

                dispatch_async(GlobalBackgroundQueue, {

                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyName = ilkEleman.value!["name"] as! String
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ = ilkEleman.value!["IQ"] as! Int
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyFirebaseID = ilkEleman.value!["uid"] as! String
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl = ilkEleman.value!["photoUrl"] as! String



            Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayChooseGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).updateChildValues(["isPlay":1])




                    dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue, {

                        self.enemyNameLbl.text = Model.sharedInstance.enemyName
                        self.enemyRank.text = "\(Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ)"
                        self.enemyImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl)!)


                    })

                })




                Model.sharedInstance.delay(2.5, closure: {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayHaneSayisi, sender: self)



                })




            }
            else if ikinciEleman.key != Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID && ikinciEleman.key != "userSayisi" {


                 print(ikinciEleman.key)
                dispatch_async(GlobalBackgroundQueue, {

                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyName = ikinciEleman.value!["name"] as! String
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ = ikinciEleman.value!["IQ"] as! Int
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyFirebaseID = ikinciEleman.value!["uid"] as! String
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl = ikinciEleman.value!["photoUrl"] as! String



                    Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayChooseGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).updateChildValues(["isPlay":1])



                    dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue, {

                        self.enemyNameLbl.text = Model.sharedInstance.enemyName
                        self.enemyRank.text = "\(Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ)"
                        self.enemyImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl)!)


                    })

                })



                Model.sharedInstance.delay(2.5, closure: {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayHaneSayisi, sender: self)


                })

            }else{


                print(ikinciEleman.key)
                dispatch_async(GlobalBackgroundQueue, {

                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyName = ucuncuEleman.value!["name"] as! String
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ = ucuncuEleman.value!["IQ"] as! Int
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyFirebaseID = ucuncuEleman.value!["uid"] as! String
                    Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl = ucuncuEleman.value!["photoUrl"] as! String



                    Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayChooseGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).updateChildValues(["isPlay":1])



                    dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue, {

                        self.enemyNameLbl.text = Model.sharedInstance.enemyName
                        self.enemyRank.text = "\(Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ)"
                        self.enemyImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl)!)


                    })

                })



                Model.sharedInstance.delay(2.5, closure: {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayHaneSayisi, sender: self)


                })


            }




        }else if snapshot.childrenCount == 2 {

            print("1 user waiting")

            Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).updateChildValues(["userSayisi":1])

        }



    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }


}
```

Join Room Code Block:

```
    func joinRoom(){

    setPlayerInfo()



    Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.queryOrderedByChild("userSayisi").queryEqualToValue(1).queryLimitedToLast(1).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in



       if snapshot.exists(){




       let odaAdi = snapshot.children.allObjects[0] as! FIRDataSnapshot


        Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi = odaAdi.key

        let interval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

        let info = ["photoUrl":Model.sharedInstance.userPictureUrl,
            "uid":Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID,
            "IQ":Model.sharedInstance.userIQ,
            "name":Model.sharedInstance.username,
            "isSiraBende":0,
            "gizliSayi":Model.sharedInstance.gizliSayi,
            "isReady":Model.sharedInstance.isReadyForPlaying,
            "isWin":Model.sharedInstance.isWin,
            "sonTahminim":Model.sharedInstance.rakipSonTahmini,
            "date":interval
        ]



      Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).setValue(info)

        Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).removeObserverWithHandle(Model.sharedInstance.handleJoinRoom)

        Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).onDisconnectRemoveValue()
        Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.QuickPlayOdaAdi).child("userSayisi").onDisconnectRemoveValue()



        Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayRoomPerGameRef.child(odaAdi.key).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            print("SnapCount: \(snapshot.childrenCount)")



                let ilkEleman = snapshot.children.allObjects[0] as! FIRDataSnapshot

                let ikinciEleman = snapshot.children.allObjects[1] as! FIRDataSnapshot

                let ucuncuEleman = snapshot.children.allObjects[2] as! FIRDataSnapshot





                if ilkEleman.key != Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID && ilkEleman.key != "userSayisi" {

                    print(ilkEleman.key)

                    dispatch_async(GlobalBackgroundQueue, {

                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyName = ilkEleman.value!["name"] as! String
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ = ilkEleman.value!["IQ"] as! Int
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyFirebaseID = ilkEleman.value!["uid"] as! String
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl = ilkEleman.value!["photoUrl"] as! String



                        Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayChooseGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).updateChildValues(["isPlay":1])



                        dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue, {

                            self.enemyNameLbl.text = Model.sharedInstance.enemyName
                            self.enemyRank.text = "\(Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ)"
                            self.enemyImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl)!)


                        })

                    })

                    Model.sharedInstance.delay(2.5, closure: {



                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayHaneSayisi, sender: self)


                    })



                }
                else if ikinciEleman.key != Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID && ikinciEleman.key != "userSayisi"{


                    print(ikinciEleman.key)
                    dispatch_async(GlobalBackgroundQueue, {

                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyName = ikinciEleman.value!["name"] as! String
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ = ikinciEleman.value!["IQ"] as! Int
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyFirebaseID = ikinciEleman.value!["uid"] as! String
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl = ikinciEleman.value!["photoUrl"] as! String



                        Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayChooseGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).updateChildValues(["isPlay":1])


                        dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue, {

                            self.enemyNameLbl.text = Model.sharedInstance.enemyName
                            self.enemyRank.text = "\(Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ)"
                            self.enemyImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl)!)


                        })

                    })

                    Model.sharedInstance.delay(2.5, closure: {




                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayHaneSayisi, sender: self)


                    })

                }
                else{

                    print(ucuncuEleman.key)
                    dispatch_async(GlobalBackgroundQueue, {

                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyName = ucuncuEleman.value!["name"] as! String
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ = ucuncuEleman.value!["IQ"] as! Int
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyFirebaseID = ucuncuEleman.value!["uid"] as! String
                        Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl = ucuncuEleman.value!["photoUrl"] as! String



                        Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayChooseGameRef.child(Model.sharedInstance.userFirebaseID).updateChildValues(["isPlay":1])


                        dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue, {

                            self.enemyNameLbl.text = Model.sharedInstance.enemyName
                            self.enemyRank.text = "\(Model.sharedInstance.enemyIQ)"
                            self.enemyImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: Model.sharedInstance.enemyPictureUrl)!)


                        })

                    })

                    Model.sharedInstance.delay(2.5, closure: {




                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Model.sharedInstance.quickPlayHaneSayisi, sender: self)


                    })


                }







        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }




       }else{

        self.createRoom()

        }


        }) { (error) in

            print(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. It would also help if you add code that shows what you've already tried. Even if you couldn't get it working, it clarifies what you're trying to accomplish and what you've already tried to get it working.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated my question, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through a `if` block with childCount condition?

Comment: yes i tried before.If 2 or more users click to join button at he same time, they can be joined. Because each one see child node count same for that time.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to handle within your security rules but you will have to change your database structure a little bit. Instead of what you have now you have to do somthing like this:

```
"QuickPlay3hanePlaying" : {
  "ByVmFbUC6HS01v4SASeA2ev33zz1" : {
    "Player1" : {
      "3s6TdUxImrNhMReJbS8kBh4I9im1" : {
        "IQ" : 1350,
        ...
        "uid" : "3s6TdUxImrNhMReJbS8kBh4I9im1"
      },
    },
    "Player2" : {
      "ByVmFbUC6HS01v4SASeA2ev33zz1" : {
        "IQ" : 1280,
        ...
        "uid" : "ByVmFbUC6HS01v4SASeA2ev33zz1"
      },
    },
    "userSayisi" : 2
  }
```

And your security rules would look like this:

```
{
"rules": {
  "QuickPlay3hanePlaying": {
    "$id": {
      "player1": {".validate": true},
      "player2":{".validate": true},
      "userSayisi": {".validate": true},
      "$other": {".validate": false}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The reason for the change in database structure is because you can only have 1 wildcard key in your security rules at a certain position.

Comment: Thanks for your response. player1 is using create room function. player2 is using join room function. So if 2 different users join room at the same time, all player2 users can be joined room. I think, i have to compare child count but i can not get child count in security rule. Thanks.